# How to select on masked indices from non-masked array?

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I just realized that my masked array doesn't work as indices for selection.

When I do mathematical operations, such as `max()` it works, but not with selections.

```
import numpy as np

array = np.arange(3,8)
indices = np.ma.masked_array(np.arange(5),np.random.randint(0,2,5))

print('array data: %s' % array)
print('indices: %s' % indices)
print('-')
print('max index: %s - ok' % indices.max())
print('selecting on indices %s - not ok' % array[indices])
```

Am I missing something? Why wouldn't the above work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to select *non* masked indices: `array[indices]`

Comment: Please provide a concrete example. It's not clear why you aren't using normal masking syntax with negation.

Comment: Use the above pls. The issue is there is it always returns 5 elements. Basically ignoring the mask, even though `indices` is a masked array.

Comment: Do you mean `array[indices[~indices.mask]]`? I just thought of it. Seems like it's working. Is this the standard syntax?

Comment: What do you mean? `array[indices.mask]` is returning different numbers of elements every time I use it. *Please provide a concrete example* of your input and expected output. Please see this post on providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Using randomly generated numbers is, almost by definition, not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
Try to play around with `n_elements`. Mask and data size must be the same.

```
import numpy as np

n_elements = 5
x = 3

array = np.arange(x, x + n_elements)

indices = np.ma.masked_array(np.arange(n_elements), 
                             np.random.randint(0, 2, n_elements))

print('array data: %s' % array)
print('indices: %s' % indices)
print('-')
print('max index: %s - ok' % indices.max())
print('selecting on indices %s' % array[indices.mask])
print('excluding on indices %s' % array[~indices.mask])
```

**ORIGINAL**
Maybe you're looking for the below?

```
array[indices.mask]
```

Comment: Won't work if we use different indices: `np.ma.masked_array(np.arange(2,4),np.random.randint(0,2,2))`

Comment: It doesn't work because you are producing a mask of 2 elements while your data has 5 elements.

Comment: Wrong. arange 2,4 is 2 element array.

Comment: Are you sure you're not still using `array = np.arange(3,8)`, which is made of 5 elements?

Comment: I do, but from array of 5 elements you can select 2 indices. duh

Comment: Yes, but data and mask must be the same size. I edited my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

Apparently, I should be using `array[indices[~indices.mask]]` instead of `array[indices]`. So instead of just specifying the indices array I should also explicitly apply it's mask on it.

Comment: Actually `array[~indices.mask]` is enough.

Comment: No it's not, if indices don't start with 0.

Comment: There is still a problem though. The result has fewer elements. It should have 5 and have some of them masked as well.